# Getting installed programs and filtering them by publisher

Tags: powershell

OK, So I can get a list of installed programs via `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | select name` but I'd really like to get a list of only select publishers say "Microsoft" and "Google".

**So programs installed:**
Adobe Reader - Adobe
iTunes       - Apple
Chrome       - Google
Visual Studio- Microsoft

**Run program Output:**
Chrome
Visual Studio

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The publisher name is stored in the `Vendor` property, so you can [filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) the results like this:

```psh
$vendors = 'Microsoft Corporation', 'Google'
$names = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product |
         ? { $vendors -contains $_.Vendor } |
         select -Expand Name
```

Fuzzy matches on a list of vendors are a little more complicated. Something like this should work, though:

```psh
$vendors = 'Microsoft', 'Google'
$names = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product |
         ? { $vendors | ? { $_.Vendor -like "*$_*" } } |
         select -Expand Name
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Believe it or not I actually did read that. My big problem with the syntax.

Comment: If your willing, is there a way to get the venders to be more flexible? Like make it where it will look for "google" but would still grab "Google ,Inc." I thought it was something like `"*google*"` but that doesn't seem to work.